# Implementing CPLEX /C++ on a software package

Tags: cplex, opl

I have an MIP model developed in OPL CPLEX, going forward I want to use C++ and prepare a package that I can distribute/sell to others as a desktop solution.

There are several options available with IBM regarding licensing, like community edition. Can anyone please guide me to obtaining the right license for what I need to do. This is a small package and I want a cheaper option, this also has to be desktop/not cloud based.

I am not from the software domain, any guidance is highly appreciated from anyone who has been through this.

Comment: Contact their support.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming but license selection / acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

Cplex community edition is [free](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/) and that can be a good starting point.

For more pricing option you should visit [IBM CPLEX Website](https://www.ibm.com/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio/pricing)

Comment: Thank you Alex for your suggestions. The community edition has a limitation of 1000 variables and 1000 constraints, my model would exceed that limit.                                                                                    I had look at the pricing ...There is a developer subscription. My query is if I were to sell the product(That I develop on C++/CPLEX along with other things)  would my clients require to pay for the CPLEX license ? Or is it enough for me to pay the developer subscription, or is there any other way.

Comment: The site did not have a direct answer on how licensing works for products sold with CPLEX. There are a few products in the market that I can see, not sure how it works between them and IBM - wanted to know on that front please.

Comment: 300+ ISV (Software Vendors) rely on CPLEX and many sign an ESA Agreement - see https://www.ibm.com/partnerworld/public/embedded-solution-agreement - but you may also let your customer buy his/her own CPLEX , anyway you should discuss this with IBM Sales